# How do I insert multiple input entries at one time in .NET Core MVC 2.2

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core

I'm running into a problem when adding multiple input entries at once. Below I have put all information I think you'll need.

**View:** http://prntscr.com/qto52o

**View code:**

```
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Studenten)
            {
                <input name="vakId" value="@vakId" style="display:none;"/>
                <input name="studentId" value="@item.Id" style="display:none;" />
                <label>@item.Voornaam @item.Tussenvoegsel @item.Achternaam</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="10" step="0.2" />
                <span id="Validation" class="text-danger"></span>
                <br />
            }
```

**Method:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GroepsResultaten(int vakId, int[] studentId, [Bind("Id,Beoordeling,StudentId,VakId")] List<Resultaat> resultatenLijst, Resultaat resultaat)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("vakId is :" + vakId);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<Student> Studenten = new List<Student>();
            foreach (var student in studentId)
            {
                resultaat.StudentId = student;
                resultaat.Beoordeling = 9;
                resultaat.VakId = vakId;
                Console.WriteLine("studentId is :" + student.ToString());
                _context.Add(resultaat);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["StudentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Student, "Id", "Voornaam", resultaat.StudentId);
        ViewData["VakId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Vak>(), "Id", "Naam", resultaat.VakId);
        return View(resultaat);
    }
```

**Models used:**

```
  public class Resultaat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Beoordeling { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public Vak Vak { get; set; }
    public int VakId { get; set; }
}
public class Vak
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Vakcode { get; set; }

    public List<Resultaat> Resultaten { get; set; }
    public List<GroepVak> Groepen { get; set; }
}
    public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Tussenvoegsel { get; set; }
    public string Studentnummer { get; set; }

    public List<Resultaat> Resultaten { get; set; }
    public List<StudentGroep> Groepen { get; set; }
}
```

Writing studentId's and subjectId's works fine in console, I think the problem is adding the values into the database.

**Edit:**

It only inserts values for the last student from the create view

Comment: Are you forgetting to call the _context.SaveChanges();_ after ending the loop?

Comment: I forgot it at first yes, now that I've included it it still only adds values for the last student from the create view

Comment: Have you tried constructing a new `resultaat` inside the loop before assigning values to it and adding it to the context?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, using `_context.Resultaat.AddRange(resultatenLijst)` worked, all I need to figure out now is how I can post the grades and assign them to the appropiate student. Now it only works with static data. Would you happen to know how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GroepsResultaten(int vakId, int[] studentId, double [] cijfers, [Bind("Id,Beoordeling,StudentId,VakId")] List<Resultaat> resultatenLijst, Resultaat resultaat)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("vakId is :" + vakId);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var student in studentId)
            {
                Resultaat res = new Resultaat
                {
                    StudentId = student,
                    Beoordeling = 3,
                    VakId = vakId
                };
                ////Console.WriteLine("current student is: " + student + " with grade: " + cijfer + " and subjectid: " + vakId);
                resultatenLijst.Add(res);
            }

            _context.Resultaat.AddRange(resultatenLijst);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["StudentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Student, "Id", "Voornaam", resultaat.StudentId);
        ViewData["VakId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Vak>(), "Id", "Naam", resultaat.VakId);
        return View(resultaat);
    }
```

It works by by creating a list of results, and adding a new result for each studentid.

Then to add a list to the db you must use .AddRange(lis)

```
_context.Resultaat.AddRange(resultatenLijst);
```

I only need to figure out how to assign the correct grades with the students, for now it only accepts static data